# How to pass an instance of an ancestor control in XAML?

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime

I'm looking to pass a property from the OuterDialog user control, into the InnerDialog as follow:

```
<uc:OuterDialog x:Name="test" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.RowSpan="2" Height="768" Width="1366" IsOpen="False">
    <uc:StandardDialog Height="768" Width="1366" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
        <uc:InnerDialog AncestorDelegate="AnotherDialog.Close">

        </uc:InnerDialog >
    </uc:StandardDialog>
</uc:OuterDialog >
```

Can I do this without resorting to code behind?

How can I get a reference to "closest" ancestor object and pass it on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to approach it would actually be to have a shared DataContext pointing to a view model that has a property that both controls synchronize with. Other than that you can use `{Binding Close, ElementName="AnotherDialog"}` to bind to a Close property on an element called AnotherDialog, assuming they are both in the same namescope..